# Automatically generate username based on user ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, registration, membership

I'm working on a WooCommerce project where each user have an ID number. I would like to use the default WooCommerce username field for this user ID.

**When creating an account, can I automatically generate an account username for the customer based on their user ID?**

[image: img]

Example:
User ID = 101,
Auto generated Username = 101

Is it possible?

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the following option is checked via the WooCommerce settings

[image]

---

Normally than you could use the `woocommerce_new_customer_username` filter hook to change the generated username.

Copied from [includes/wc-user-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/085b4b53fae187b0669714bc9da4e3084ba318d8/includes/wc-user-functions.php)

```php
/**
 * Filter new customer username.
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 * @param string $username      Customer username.
 * @param string $email         New customer email address.
 * @param array  $new_user_args Array of new user args, maybe including first and last names.
 * @param string $suffix        Append string to username to make it unique.
 */
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_customer_username', $username, $email, $new_user_args, $suffix );
```

However, you want to determine the `$username` based on the `$user_id`,
but the `$user_id` is determined after data such as username, email address, etc. has been added via [wp_insert_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)

---

So the solution is to update the `$username` based on the `$user_id` immediately after a user is registered, and this can be done via:

Copied from [wp-includes/user.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php) (WordPress)

```php
/**
 * Fires immediately after a new user is registered.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param int $user_id User ID.
 */
do_action( 'user_register', $user_id );
```

And

- [wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) - WordPress database access abstraction class.
- [update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/) - Update user meta field based on user ID.

---

So you get:

```php
function action_user_register( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Set new name + nickname
    $new_name = 'something_' . $user_id;
    
    // Update user user_login
    $wpdb -> update( $wpdb -> users, 
        array( 'user_login' => $new_name, 'user_nicename' => $new_name, 'display_name' => $new_name ), 
        array( 'ID' => $user_id )
    );
    
    // Update user meta
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $new_name );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $new_name );
} 
add_action( 'user_register', 'action_user_register', 10, 1 );
```

Note: Know that a customer/user can change some of these adjustments via his profile (my account), if you do not want this, you will have to make additional adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much @7uc1f3r .When I use this code, the first and last names I typed during registration do not appear in the admin panel.

Comment: If you look at my answer you will see that 5 values ​​are being adjusted. (User login, user nickname 2x, display name and firstname). So it is a matter of adding or removing those values ​​based on what you exactly want to adjust.

Comment: Now everything is working very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You can edit the `wp_insert_user` function that creates the user and change parameters. This function requires an array (or object) of user data to create the user so you just add whatever you want to `user_login`. All parameters and examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/).

**Option 2**

If you can't edit the `wp_insert_user` function you can always call a custom SQL query to update `user_login`:

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_login' => $new_user_login), array('ID' => $user_id));
```

Ideally use a hook/action just after user registration.